# Why do I get a duplicate column name error only when I SELECT FROM (SELECT)

Tags: sql, select, nested, derived-table

I imagine this is a really basic oversight on my part but I have an SQL query which works fine. But I when I SELECT from that result `(SELECT FROM (SELECT))` 
I get a 'duplicate column' error. There are duplicate column names, for sure, in two tables where I compare them but they do not cause a problem in the initial result. For example:

```
SELECT _dia_tagsrel.tag_id,_dia_tagsrel.article_id, _dia_tags.tag_id, _dia_tags.tag
FROM _dia_tagsrel
JOIN _dia_tags
ON _dia_tagsrel.tag_id = _dia_tags.tag_id
```

Works fine but when I try to select from it, I get the error:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT tag FROM
(SELECT _dia_tagsrel.tag_id,_dia_tagsrel.article_id, _dia_tags.tag_id, _dia_tags.tag
    FROM _dia_tagsrel
    JOIN _dia_tags
    ON _dia_tagsrel.tag_id = _dia_tags.tag_id) a
```

Regardless of the DISTINCT. Ok, I can change the column names to be unique but the question really is - why do i get the error when I SELECT FROM (SELECT) and not in the initial query?
Thanks

Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_id, tag FROM (SELECT  _dia_tagsrel.tag_id, _dia_tagsrel.article_id,  _dia_tags.tag
FROM _dia_tagsrel
JOIN _dia_tags
ON _dia_tagsrel.tag_id = _dia_tags.tag_id) a
```

I only needed to SELECT one of the duplicate columns, even though I was comparing the both of them. Provided by answer below.

Comment: I can only think that I need to alias the duplicate column names in the initial query?

Comment: In latter case you create derived table, which follows table semantics. Column names must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query returns four columns:

- `tag_id`
- `article_id`
- `tag_id`
- `tag`

Duplicate column names are allowed in a *result set*, but are not allowed in a *table* -- or derived table, view, CTE, or most subqueries (an exception are `EXISTS` subqueries).

I hope you can see the duplicate.  There is no need to select `tag_id` twice, because the `JOIN` requires that the values are the same.  So just select three columns:

```
SELECT tr.tag_id, tr.article_id, t.tag
FROM _dia_tagsrel tr JOIN
     _dia_tags t
     ON tr.tag_id = t.tag_id
```

Comment: Hi, so - without renaming the initial columns, would returning these columns as aliases work? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as my answer. I was under the impression that I needed to select the columns that I use to compare, so instead I have just left them out. So In fact I only need to select from 2 columns - article_id and tag and it works.

Answer (score 2):

In you are second query i.e., the sub query, you are selecting tag_id twice. Though it is from two different tables, it works out whey you are selecting the data. But when you select the columns with same name twice, it provides you duplicate error. Below is the way you have selected the column which is incorrect
      **_dia_tagsrel.tag_id**,_dia_tagsrel.article_id, **_dia_tags.tag_id**, _dia_tags.tag
 While using sub queries, merge, in or exists clause, avoid using the same column names multiple times.

Simple join works out no need of having subquery,

```
SELECT _dia_tagsrel.tag_id,_dia_tagsrel.article_id, _dia_tags.tag_id, _dia_tags.tag
FROM _dia_tagsrel
JOIN _dia_tags
ON _dia_tagsrel.tag_id = _dia_tags.tag_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I now realise thanks in part to @GordonLinoff that the derived table cannot distinguish the duplicates. So I am to either leave them off (as I only need them to compare), or create an alias.

Comment: That's correct Gavin. Can you please provide an up vote so that others can also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery has two `tag_id`s, so how database engine decide which one you want to use.

So, either use one (join requires `tag_id`s to be same) or re-name it :

If `_dia_tag` has unique `tag`s then you can use `EXISTS` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.tag
FROM _dia_tags t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM _dia_tagsrel tr WHERE tr.tag_id = t.tag_id);
```